# How can I stop my balls from being moved to random places when I add new bouncy balls in an HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I currently have a program that when you hit an "Add Ball" button, a new ball gets created and they bounce off the walls and other balls. However, let's say you already have two other balls and you hit the "Add Ball" button: the two old balls will randomly be created somewhere else (where it was not originally).

**Question**: How can I stop my balls from going to random locations every time I hit the "Add Ball" button?

```js
function lineMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').textContent += msg + '. ';
}

function groupMessage(msg) {
    document.querySelector('#myMessage').innerHTML += msg + '<br/>';
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 550;
const ballCount = document.querySelector('#ball-count');

const gravity = 0;
const wallLoss = 1;
let numBalls = 0;  // approx as will not add ball if space can not be found
const minBallSize = 13;
const maxBallSize = 20;
const velMin = 1;
const velMax = 5; 
const maxResolutionCycles = 100;

function addBall() {
    numBalls++;
    ballCount.innerHTML = numBalls;

    Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
    Math.rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    Math.randI = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min | 0; // only for positive numbers 32bit signed int
    Math.randItem = arr => arr[Math.random() * arr.length | 0]; // only for arrays with length < 2 ** 31 - 1
    // contact points of two circles radius r1, r2 moving along two lines (a,e)-(b,f) and (c,g)-(d,h) [where (,) is coord (x,y)]
    Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime = (a, e, b, f, c, g, d, h, r1, r2) => { // args (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, r1, r2)
        const A = a * a, B = b * b, C = c * c, D = d * d;
        const E = e * e, F = f * f, G = g * g, H = h * h;
        var R = (r1 + r2) ** 2;
        const AA = A + B + C + F + G + H + D + E + b * c + c * b + f * g + g * f + 2 * (a * d - a * b - a * c - b * d - c * d - e * f + e * h - e * g - f * h - g * h);
        const BB = 2 * (-A + a * b + 2 * a * c - a * d - c * b - C + c * d - E + e * f + 2 * e * g - e * h - g * f - G + g * h);
        const CC = A - 2 * a * c + C + E - 2 * e * g + G - R;
        return Math.quadRoots(AA, BB, CC);
    }  

    Math.quadRoots = (a, b, c) => { // find roots for quadratic
        if (Math.abs(a) < 1e-6) {
            return b != 0 ? [-c / b] : [] 
        }

        b /= a;
        var d = b * b - 4 * (c / a);

        if (d > 0) {
            d = d ** 0.5;
            return  [0.5 * (-b + d), 0.5 * (-b - d)]
        }

        return d === 0 ? [0.5 * -b] : [];
    }

    Math.interceptLineBallTime = (x, y, vx, vy, x1, y1, x2, y2, r) => {
        const xx = x2 - x1;
        const yy = y2 - y1;
        const d = vx * yy - vy * xx;

        if (d > 0) {  // only if moving towards the line
            const dd = r / (xx * xx + yy * yy) ** 0.5;
            const nx = xx * dd;
            const ny = yy * dd;
            return (xx * (y - (y1 + nx)) - yy * (x - (x1 - ny))) / d;
        }
    }

    const balls = [];
    const lines = [];

    function Line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    Line.prototype = {
        draw() {
            ctx.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1);
            ctx.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2);
        },
        reverse() {
            const x = this.x1;
            const y = this.y1;
            this.x1 = this.x2;
            this.y1 = this.y2;
            this.x2 = x;
            this.y2 = y;
            return this;
        }
    }
        
    function Ball(x, y, vx, vy, r = 45, m = 4 / 3 * Math.PI * (r ** 3)) {
        this.r = r;
        this.m = m;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.vx = vx;
        this.vy = vy;
    }

    Ball.prototype = {
        update() {
            this.x += this.vx;
            this.y += this.vy;
            this.vy += gravity;
        },
        draw() {
            ctx.moveTo(this.x + this.r, this.y);
            ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.TAU);
        },
        interceptLineTime(l, time) {
            const u = Math.interceptLineBallTime(this.x, this.y, this.vx, this.vy, l.x1, l.y1, l.x2, l.y2, this.r);

            if (u >= time && u <= 1) {
                return u;
            }
        },
        checkBallBallTime(t, minTime) {
            return t > minTime && t <= 1;
        },
        interceptBallTime(b, time) {
            const x = this.x - b.x;
            const y = this.y - b.y;
            const d = (x * x + y * y) ** 0.5;

            if (d > this.r + b.r) {
                const times = Math.circlesInterceptUnitTime(
                    this.x, this.y, 
                    this.x + this.vx, this.y + this.vy, 
                    b.x, b.y,
                    b.x + b.vx, b.y + b.vy, 
                    this.r, b.r
                )

                if (times.length) {
                    if (times.length === 1) {
                        if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                            return times[0]
                        }

                        return;
                    }

                    if (times[0] <= times[1]) {
                        if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                            return times[0]
                        }

                        if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) {
                            return times[1]
                        }

                        return
                    }

                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[1], time)) { 
                        return times[1]
                    }      

                    if (this.checkBallBallTime(times[0], time)) {
                        return times[0]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        collideLine(l, time) {
            const x1 = l.x2 - l.x1;
            const y1 = l.y2 - l.y1;
            const d = (x1 * x1 + y1 * y1) ** 0.5;
            const nx = x1 / d;
            const ny = y1 / d;            
            const u = (this.vx  * nx + this.vy  * ny) * 2;
            this.x += this.vx * time;   
            this.y += this.vy * time;   
            this.vx = (nx * u - this.vx) * wallLoss;
            this.vy = (ny * u - this.vy) * wallLoss;
            this.x -= this.vx * time;
            this.y -= this.vy * time;
        },
        collide(b, time) {
            const a = this;
            const m1 = a.m;
            const m2 = b.m;
            const x = a.x - b.x
            const y = a.y - b.y  
            const d = (x * x + y * y);
            const u1 = (a.vx * x + a.vy * y) / d
            const u2 = (x * a.vy - y * a.vx ) / d
            const u3 = (b.vx * x + b.vy * y) / d
            const u4 = (x * b.vy - y * b.vx ) / d
            const mm = m1 + m2;
            const vu3 = (m1 - m2) / mm * u1 + (2 * m2) / mm * u3;
            const vu1 = (m2 - m1) / mm * u3 + (2 * m1) / mm * u1;
            a.x = a.x + a.vx * time;
            a.y = a.y + a.vy * time;
            b.x = b.x + b.vx * time;
            b.y = b.y + b.vy * time;
            b.vx = x * vu1 - y * u4;
            b.vy = y * vu1 + x * u4;
            a.vx = x * vu3 - y * u2;
            a.vy = y * vu3 + x * u2;
            a.x = a.x - a.vx * time;
            a.y = a.y - a.vy * time;
            b.x = b.x - b.vx * time;
            b.y = b.y - b.vy * time;
        },
        doesOverlap(ball) {
            const x = this.x - ball.x;
            const y = this.y - ball.y;
            return  (this.r + ball.r) > ((x * x + y * y) ** 0.5);  
        }       
    }

    function canAdd(ball) {
        for (const b of balls) {
            if (ball.doesOverlap(b)) {
                return false
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    function create(bCount) {
        lines.push(new Line(-10, 10, ctx.canvas.width + 10, 5));
        lines.push((new Line(-10, ctx.canvas.height - 2, ctx.canvas.width + 10, ctx.canvas.height - 10)).reverse());
        lines.push((new Line(10, -10, 4, ctx.canvas.height + 10)).reverse());
        lines.push(new Line(ctx.canvas.width - 3, -10, ctx.canvas.width - 10, ctx.canvas.height + 10)); 

        while (bCount--) {
            let tries = 100;
            debugger

            while (tries--) {
                const dir = Math.rand(0, Math.TAU);
                const vel = Math.rand(velMin, velMax);
                const ball = new Ball(
                    Math.rand(maxBallSize + 10, canvas.width - maxBallSize - 10), 
                    Math.rand(maxBallSize + 10, canvas.height - maxBallSize - 10),
                    Math.cos(dir) * vel,
                    Math.sin(dir) * vel,
                    Math.rand(minBallSize, maxBallSize),
                )

                if (canAdd(ball)) {
                    balls.push(ball);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function resolveCollisions() {
        var minTime = 0, minObj, minBall, resolving = true, idx = 0, idx1, after = 0, e = 0;
        
        while (resolving && e++ < maxResolutionCycles) { // too main ball may create very lone resolution cycle. e limits this
            resolving = false;
            minObj = undefined;
            minBall = undefined;
            minTime = 1;
            idx = 0;

            for(const b of balls) {
                idx1 = idx + 1;
                while (idx1 < balls.length) {
                    const b1 = balls[idx1++];
                    const time = b.interceptBallTime(b1, after);

                    if (time !== undefined) {
                        if (time <= minTime) {
                            minTime = time;
                            minObj = b1;
                            minBall = b;
                            resolving = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (const l of lines) {
                    const time = b.interceptLineTime(l, after);
                    if (time !== undefined) {
                        if (time <= minTime) {
                            minTime = time;
                            minObj = l;
                            minBall = b;
                            resolving = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                idx++;
            }

            if (resolving) {
                if (minObj instanceof Ball) {
                    minBall.collide(minObj, minTime);
                } else {
                    minBall.collideLine(minObj, minTime);
                }

                after = minTime;
            }
        }
    }

    create(numBalls);
    mainLoop();

    function mainLoop() {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
        resolveCollisions();

        for (const b of balls) {
            b.update()
        }

        ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
        ctx.beginPath();

        for (const b of balls) {
            b.draw()
        }

        for (const l of lines) {
            l.draw()
        }

        ctx.stroke();
        requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    }
}
```

```css
#canvas {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 550px
}

#myConsole {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Christian Davis">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <title>Bouncy Balls</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="addBall()">Add Ball</button><br>
        <div>Ball Count: <span id="ball-count">0</span></div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <p id="myConsole">&gt;&nbsp;<span id="myMessage"></span></p>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aside: Why do you reassign all the `Math.xxx` properties every time you call `addBall()`? Just do it once when you start the program.

Comment: @Barmar Originally, I wasn't actually going to do an "add ball" method, I just decided to do it earlier. So my code is built off of a different idea.

Comment: `addBall()` calls `create()`, which creates all the balls from scratch. It should just add one new ball, not start over. You have too much stuff nested inside `addBall()`. All the functions and classes should be at top-level, not inside that function.

Comment: @Bamar After trying to move more outside of the add ball method, the code didn't work and just gave multiple errors. Thank you for the idea, but it did not assist me to a greater end.

Comment: @ThatNewCoder Barmar's advice is good and correctly explains the problem. If you encountered multiple errors, try fixing them, because this is the right approach. It's normal to take some work to undo a misguided design--better than doubling down on it, implementing a hack or workaround, and running into even worse refactoring problems later.

Comment: Sorry, but the complete rewrite that's needed to fix this is more than I'm willing to do for a SO answer. You need to start over and think more carefully about what you're doing. While you're at it, stop using prototype-based coding and learn ES6 classes. And there's no need to modify built-in modules like `Math`, just define ordinary functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems. The main problem is that you have put everything in the `addBall` function. For example, the array `balls` is defined in that function, so every time you press the "Add Ball"-button, you discard all your old balls and create new ones with new random positions.

The first thing I did was move everything but the code to add a ball from `addBall`. With this new code I removed the 'create' function but kept the body inside the 'addBall'. It now looks like this:

```
function addBall() {
  numBalls++;
  ballCount.innerHTML = numBalls;

  lines.push(new Line(-10, 10, ctx.canvas.width + 10, 5));
  lines.push(new Line(-10, ctx.canvas.height - 2, ctx.canvas.width + 10, ctx.canvas.height - 10).reverse());
  lines.push(new Line(10, -10, 4, ctx.canvas.height + 10).reverse());
  lines.push(new Line(ctx.canvas.width - 3, -10, ctx.canvas.width - 10, ctx.canvas.height + 10));

  let tries = 100;

  while (tries--) {
    const dir = rand(0, TAU);
    const vel = rand(velMin, velMax);
    const ball = new Ball(
      rand(maxBallSize + 10, canvas.width - maxBallSize - 10),
      rand(maxBallSize + 10, canvas.height - maxBallSize - 10),
      Math.cos(dir) * vel,
      Math.sin(dir) * vel,
      rand(minBallSize, maxBallSize)
    );

    if (canAdd(ball)) {
      balls.push(ball);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I also removed the call to `mainLoop()` from inside the `addBall` function, because otherwise it will be called once for each ball, but since the function handles all the balls, the balls will go faster and faster with each added ball.

I also converted the old prototype defined classes to ES6 syntax, moved the added functions to Math to standalone functions. I know this is your own code, but it is considered very bad practice to add extra functionality to native objects, unless they are polyfills that add functionality not implemented in the current engine.

Since you tried to move the functionality outside of `addBall` but failed, I will give you an overview of how the code can be refactored. I haven't done any other analysis of the code, just copied your code, so there are still things to improve. For example, you are adding lines for each ball, which you probably don't want. If you move `numBalls++` inside the if statement, the variable is only incremented if a ball was actually added. Even better is to remove `numBalls` and use the length of the `balls` array: `ballCount.innerHTML = balls.length;`

```
const TAU = Math.PI * 2;

const balls = [];
const lines = [];

function rand(min, max) {}
function circlesInterceptUnitTime(a, e, b, f, c, g, d, h, r1, r2) {}
function quadRoots(a, b, c) {}
function interceptLineBallTime(x, y, vx, vy, x1, y1, x2, y2, r) {}
function lineMessage(msg) {}
function groupMessage(msg) {}

class Ball {
  constructor(x, y, vx, vy, r = 45, m = (4 / 3) * Math.PI * r ** 3) {}
  update() {}
  draw() {}
  interceptLineTime(l, time) {}
  checkBallBallTime(t, minTime) {}
  interceptBallTime(b, time) {}
  collideLine(l, time) {}
  collide(b, time) {}
  doesOverlap(ball) {}
}

class Line {
  constructor(x1, y1, x2, y2) {}
  draw() {}
  reverse() {}
}

function resolveCollisions() {}
function mainLoop() {}   
function canAdd(ball) {}

const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 1000;
canvas.height = 550;
const ballCount = document.querySelector('#ball-count');

const gravity = 0;
const wallLoss = 1;
let numBalls = 0; 
const minBallSize = 13;
const maxBallSize = 20;
const velMin = 1;
const velMax = 5;
const maxResolutionCycles = 100;

function addBall() {}

mainLoop(); // Only one call to mainLoop
```